# Is there a way to keep a file in a GIT repository and remove it locally without committing the deletion?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a specific requirement for a project to keep a folder called `install` in the remote repository which was added to `.gitignore` after committing. This folder is only required to set up the application and has to be removed after installation. Is it possible to remove this `install` directory from the local repository without committing the deletion? The folder must be available in the remote repository, but after the first time setting it up, the directory must be removed.

Comment: Git is not an install tool. I would suggest instead adding an installation tool to your project.

Answer (score 3):

The intent of git is to manage version control for artifacts. That could be code, images, binary files. It could even be release artifacts, although this is a bit more tricky and Git isn't necessarily suited best for that.

The issue here, is that you appear to have two different activities going on

1. Pull down and install the latest version of something
2. Work on that thing or use it after the fact

My pushback on that requirement, if it were given to me, is that the 2 different activities above require different approaches and shouldn't be in the same repo. Development and release are separate and need to be handled with different processes (and sometimes, different tools).

Typically, you create some kind of install package or distribution from your development repo, which is built from the data in the repo. For distribution, you would save a package distribution somewhere, such as an npm package repository for Node.JS, or PyPi for Python. Alternately, you can distribute the package through a release method like the Release page on Github for your repo, or a special repo built for releases, like Artifactory or Docker Trusted Repo (more for Docker Containers...).

You can also store the distribution as you're being asked to do, but then normally you would have a separate repo to store that in, so your developers don't have to download the latest distribution when getting the latest commit. Whenever a distribution is created, you would put the install files into the folder for that repo (such as a local `install` folder) and push a new commit. Then people can clone that or install directly from the repo (i.e. download the file(s) directly from the Github page of the remote install repo).

However, it is possible, though it's still a little hacky, to potentially have a separate branch where the release folders exist, but in the main dev or master branch, they do not. If you have no choice or ability to suggest a better solution, that is the way I'd go.

Answer (score 1):

There's another good answer already, but I'd like to address this particular point directly:

> Is it possible to remove this install directory from the local repository without committing the deletion?

No—and it's easy to see *why* that's the case, when you consider what Git actually stores.

Each commit, with its unique hash ID number, actually *stores* **all** of your files as a snapshot, in a special, read-only (frozen for all time), Git-only, de-duplicated format.<sup>1</sup>  These commits thus stand on their own: you don't actually *need* a previous commit, which is how Git allows shallow clones to exist.<sup>2</sup>

To make a new commit, you have Git re-save *every* file (de-duplicated, so all the unchanged files just re-use the previous one).  To make a commit that doesn't have some set of files (`install/*`), you have to make a commit that doesn't have the files.  That is, you have to commit the deletion.  The commits that *do* have the files remain in the repository, and should anyone, any time in the future, make a commit that contains a file that exactly matches one of those `install/*` files, Git will automatically de-duplicate it.

See [LightCC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63271000/1256452) to address what you can do instead of what you are doing now, that's causing some pain.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, these are either *loose objects*, which are Git objects of type `blob` that are just a zlib-compressed form of the file with a prefix—you can read these in various languages using a zlib-decompressor and then skipping the header—or *packed objects*, which then use delta-compression and are therefore much harder to read.  Git reserves to itself the right to change the internal storage format in the future, so it's generally best to just have Git extract the object, turning it back into an ordinary everyday file.

<sup>2</sup>Shallow clones are still tricky, and in particular, when *pushing* from a shallow clone, Git might not realize that some other Git already has many files, and will re-send them and force the other Git to re-de-duplicate them.